# Docker container log file not found on Mac

Tags: macos, docker

I am trying to find the docker container log file on Mac.  The container is still running.

I can see output from `docker logs es5`.
Run

```
docker inspect -f {{.LogPath}} es5
```

and I got a the filename.

> /var/lib/docker/containers/3ac5831155da80986cf7cd45889ce5015cd5b8b0b1d667fa2f66a4da2745caef/3ac5831155da80986cf7cd45889ce5015cd5b8b0b1d667fa2f66a4da2745caef-json.log

However, when I `cat` the file, it can't be found.

```
cat \`docker inspect -f {{.LogPath}} es5\`
```

> cat: /var/lib/docker/containers/3ac5831155da80986cf7cd45889ce5015cd5b8b0b1d667fa2f66a4da2745caef/3ac5831155da80986cf7cd45889ce5015cd5b8b0b1d667fa2f66a4da2745caef-json.log: No such file or directory

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 19):

To access /var/lib/docker/containers/ , try

`screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

in new versions of docker.

Comment: should probably be `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty` since `~/` refers to the user's HOME directory

Comment: I don't see a `tty` file there at all.

Answer (score 15):

Container logs are stored inside Docker for Mac VM not on your MacOS host. You can enter into VM with `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty` command and then cat the log file.

Please see [Screen Commands for Docker for Mac](https://gist.github.com/BretFisher/5e1a0c7bcca4c735e716abf62afad389) for additional info

Answer (score 2):

They are within docker-desktop (LinuxKit), not in the host.

Cat them like this:

```bash
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i cat /var/lib/docker/containers/3ac5831155da80986cf7cd45889ce5015cd5b8b0b1d667fa2f66a4da2745caef/3ac5831155da80986cf7cd45889ce5015cd5b8b0b1d667fa2f66a4da2745caef-json.log
```

but then again `docker logs es5` would have been the same...

You can directly create a shell to docker-descktop:

```bash
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh
```

Already answered here: [How do I access the Docker CE virtual machine on MacOS BigSur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66669224/how-do-i-access-the-docker-ce-virtual-machine-on-macos-bigsur)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Docker desktop and was not able to find the log file.

I found the following and it worked perfectly

https://blog.tkuchiki.net/en/clear-docker-container-logs-docker-for-mac

Comment: link broken, still can access from archive https://web.archive.org/web/20210411174622/https://blog.tkuchiki.net/en/clear-docker-container-logs-docker-for-mac

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

- Make the tty file readable: `chmod 400 ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`
- Do not execute that file, but read its contents: `screen $(cat ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty)`. Press `Enter`

Comment: I don't see a `tty` file there at all.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier did you manage to locate the log file. I am having the same issue, I can't find the tty