# where is logs file kept in docker container and how to copy it?

Tags: docker

i have a dockerfile like this.

when i docker compose up the service, i can use command to view logs.

```
docker test -f logs
```

i want to copy the logs file to my local machine.

where is the path?

docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-alpine AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything else and build
COPY ./ /app/
RUN dotnet restore -r linux-musl-x64 -s http://nexus.thedevcloud.net/repository/nuget-group/
RUN dotnet publish -r linux-musl-x64 -c Release -o DrugSync/out --no-restore

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false 
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/test/out/ /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/test"]
```

Answer (score 2):

- Log files can be found at:

`/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-xxx.log`

Where *xxx* stands for different formats based on how you have configured it.

- You can docker inspect each container to see where their logs are:

`docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $INSTANCE_ID`

More details about configuring logging is [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)

EDIT:

- Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017329/where-is-a-log-file-with-logs-from-a-container)
- Also I tried it on mine at it shows up:

`$ docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' 878eb2faac5c`

> /var/lib/docker/containers/878eb2faac5c9fe743fd9e9e6ba6ff7e0c3f1e02964df77e5a788dcd985c0d0b/878eb2faac5c9fe743fd9e9e6ba6ff7e0c3f1e02964df77e5a788dcd985c0d0b-json.log

Note:

On Mac machines this location would be on the VM hosting the docker containers and not on the MacOS Host.

Try `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty` to access the location.

Comment: i did not find /var/lib/docker folder. inside /var/lib no docker folder. anything i missed in docker file?

Comment: i am using docker desktop windows , linux container at windows 10. i did not see instance id when i docker ps

Comment: use docker ps -a

Comment: did u mean container id?

Comment: docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' af3f1ad82cde
'/var/lib/docker/containers/af3f1ad82cdeea41756fc62897c7b734d17b2fbc75749174283a6db9024d756b/af3f1ad82cdeea41756fc62897c7b734d17b2fbc75749174283a6db9024d756b-json.log'

Comment: how do i navigate to the path? i used docker exec -it test /bin/sh

Comment: First get the container id using `$docker ps -a` then  `$docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' your_continerid`

Comment: docker exec -it test /bin/sh . then cd .. then cd var/lib , there is no docker folder

Comment: yes i got the long string-json.log but i cannot navigate to that path...i just want to copy it out to my machine

Comment: i think it might be a problem with non-linux machines. Maybe try to pipe the `docker logs your_containerid` into some file

Comment: On Mac and Windows, it uses VM to run the docker containers so the location might be not on the base machine but on the VM. To access it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180981/docker-container-log-file-not-found-on-mac

Comment: okay that is for mac...any idea how to do it at windows? or any tool?

Comment: Try this: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-70-gain-access-to-the-mobylinux-vm-on-windows-or-macos

Comment: no luck / # du -chs /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*json.log
du: /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*json.log: No such file or directory
0       total

Comment: does the path `/var/lib/docker/containers/`at least exist now?

Comment: nope. as i mentioned earlier, the problem is i cannot find the relevant path